# What is pulse-by-pulse shutdown and latching PWM to prevent multiple pulses?

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm, datasheet

I was looking into the [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/23564/STMICROELECTRONICS/SG3525AN.html) of SG3525AN, and its features include pulse-by-pulse shutdown and latching PWM to prevent multiple pulses. What does pulse-by-pulse shutdown and latching PWM to prevent multiple pulses mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older part.  THe PWM pulses occur at the oscillator frequency.  The data sheet is touting the fact that when a shutdown signal is asserted during a PWM pulse, the pulse is truncated.  Further, if the shutdown signal is removed, the output is not immediately turned back on, but stays off until the beginning of the next PWM pulse, so that short shutdown signals will not break a single PWM pulse into two or more pulses.  Instead, the part waits until the beginning of the next PWM period.